# Render Plotly chart without background

Tags: python, django, charts, plotly

I have a Plotly donut chart rendering in my Django template that comes with a default white background. I can't figure out how to render it without the background.

I know how to make the background transparent but when I try to resize the chart, obviously the background is still there and it stretches the div or if I make the chart smaller so it fits then its too small and unreadable.

Is there a way to get rid of the background all together? Or maybe I should use something other than Plotly?

Thanks for your help!

```py
    import plotly.graph_objects as go

    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values, hole=.3)])
    fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)', width=300, height=300,)
    chart = fig.to_html()
```

Comment: Can you show us what you mean when you say the background still stretches the div?

Comment: If I set the chart height to 300px then its the background that is 300px with the pie chart that is maybe 100px in size in the middle. I need the chart to be 100px without the extra 100 on top and bottom.

Comment: it sounds like ideally you'd want to be able to isolate or crop just the pie chart. maybe try changing the `default_width` and `default_height` arguments in the `.to_html` method. something like `fig.to_html(default_width=300, default_height=300)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the margins of the plot. You might also want to move the legend.  See below.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

labels = ['green','red','blue']
values = [1,2,3]
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values, hole=.3)])
    paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)', 
    width=300, 
    height=300)


# Change margins
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    margin=dict(
        l=2,
        r=0,
        b=1,
        t=1,
        pad=2
    ),
)

# Move legend
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    yanchor="top",
    y=0.95,
    xanchor="left",
    x=0.87
))
```

[image]

Comment: As I stated and demonstrated in my question, I already have the background set as transparent. But even though you cant see the background, the height and width I set for the chart includes the background.

Comment: Ah. Sorry. Totally misread your question. I will delete this.

Comment: @RyanThomas I've edited my post.

Comment: Thanks for that solution!